# Order of creating @Inject objects

Tags: java, cdi, inject

Look at following class (please note, that it is not a singleton):

```
public MyClass() {

    @Inject private A a;
    @Inject private B b;

}
```

What object will be created first `a` or `b`?

Is there a possibility of determine the order of creating objects?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't answer your question, however, I can advice you to take a hard look at your classes and try to figure out how not to depend on the order of object instantiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can very much control order.  First, assume that they have normal scopes (e.g. `@RequestScoped`).  Second, make `B` have a reference to `A`.  You'll see that `A` gets instantiated first, then `B`.  Note that you'll need to track via your `@PostConstruct` method.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so and I don't see a reason why it should matter (I am also afraid that order of object instantiation can change from deployment to deployment). You are guaranteed to have all objects injected in `@PostConstruct` and that's the most important thing (as far as I am concerned).